# Magento 2 - get cache url of media gallery images of product

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, product-images, media

This is my code for get cache url of images:

```
$images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach($images as $child){
            echo '"'.$child->getUrl().'"';
}
```

Result expected: `pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1cd59219f95f9c415e6b76e445689a097/J/K/JK791735.jpg`

---

Result obtained: `pub/media/catalog/product/J/K/JK791735.jpg`

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get cached images from a product object with this:

```
foreach($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $k=>$image){

    $thumbnailImage = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'category_page_grid')
        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
        ->getUrl();
    $largeImage = $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
        ->getUrl();
}
```

where `$this->imageHelper` is the instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image`

1. `category_page_grid` is used to get image which will be equal to the size in product list page
2. `product_page_image_large` is used to get large size image

Comment: Man i tried but returns blank page...I tried your code in product page!

Comment: check error log, you are probably getting an error with implementation

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor::$imageHelper

Comment: I found the solution man! I added: $imagehelper = $this-> helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image'); So i replaced $this->imageHelper in foreach with $imagehelper and works!

Comment: Great, good to hear that :)